# IdentityServer3, Autofac, IdentityFramework in existing project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, autofac, identityserver3

I have been playing around with IdentityServer3 with the hopes to replace our current authentication process.
Currently we use a custom identity framework process using code first entity framework.
I managed to install IdentityServer3 and get the "in memory" stuff working. Now I want to hook it up to our already customised `UserProvider` (`UserManager` if you like).

We already use Autofac and have our `UserProvider` registered like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<UserProvider>().As<IUserProvider>().InstancePerDependency();
```

I found some documentation that states that [IdentityServer uses Autofac](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-using-ASPNET-Identity) itself.
They recommend creating a factory and then using `IdentityServerOptions` to register the user service like this:

```
options.Factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(UserServiceFactory.Create())
```

The problem I have with that, is the factory looks something like this:

```
public class UserServiceFactory
{
    public static AspNetIdentityUserService<User, string> Create()
    {
        var context = new IdentityDbContext();
        var userStore = new UserStore<User>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore);

        return new AspNetIdentityUserService<User, string>(userManager);
    }
}
```

Which is using the normal **UserManager** rather than our customised version **and** it isn't using DI because you create it all in the static method.
Surely it would be better to use Autofac as we already have our **UserProvider** registered.
So, I didn't use their **IdentityServerOptions** to invoke the static method. So I changed my factory to this:

```
public class IdentityServerUserService : UserServiceBase
{
    private readonly IUserProvider _userProvider;

    public IdentityServerUserService(IUserProvider userProvider)
    {
        _userProvider = userProvider;
    }

    public override async Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(LocalAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        var user = await _userProvider.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user != null && !user.Disabled)
        {
            // Get the UserClaims

            // Add the user to our context
            context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.Id, user.UserName, new List<Claim>());
        }
    }
}
```

Which I registered in autofac like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<IdentityServerUserService>()
       .As<IdentityServer3.Core.Services.IUserService>()
       .InstancePerDependency();
```

And then I assigned to the `IdentityServerOptions.Factory.UserService` like this:

```
private static void SetupServices(IdentityServerOptions options, ILifetimeScope scope)
{
    options.Factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(scope.Resolve<IdentityServerUserService>());
}
```

And the scope I get like this:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
var scope = config.DependencyResolver.GetRootLifetimeScope();
```

I believe this should work, but I get an error when I try to use postman to authenticate:

> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Business.IdentityServerUserService' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

I tried to change from `InstancePerDependency` to `InstancePerLifetimeScope` but still got the same error.

So, I have a couple of questions:

- Is this the right way to assign the UserService?
- Will this allow my existing users to authenticate?
- Has anyone done this before? If so, did they get it to work?

If anyone can help me with these questions, I would be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You resolve `IdentityServerUserService` but you register `IdentityServerUserService` as `IUserService`. Autofac doesn't automatically register the type as itself.

To fix the error you can register the type as itself

```
builder.RegisterType<IdentityServerUserService>()
       .As<IdentityServer3.Core.Services.IUserService>()
       .InstancePerDependency();
```

or resolve `IUserService`

```
options.Factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(scope.Resolve<IUserService>())
```